# cannot run hyperledger chaincode from my own github on Ubuntu terminal

Tags: go, ubuntu-16.04, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I can run the chaincode from the following official path:
https://github.com/ibm-blockchain/learn-chaincode/finished
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go/chaincode_example02

```
# peer chaincode deploy -p github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go/chaincode_example02 -c '{"Function":"init", "Args": ["a","100", "b", "200"]}'
```

but cannot run chainncode from my own github path:
https://github.com/jeffyxia/hyperledger/trade

```
# peer chaincode deploy -p https://github.com/jeffyxia/hyperledger/trade -c '{"Function":"init", "Args": ["a","100", "b", "200"]}'
```

the error info is:

Error: Error building chaincode: rpc error: code = 2 desc = Error getting

```
chaincode package bytes: Error getting code 'go get' failed with error: "exit status 2"
# github.com/jeffyxia/hyperledger/hello_world
/go/_usercode_/519629987/src/github.com/jeffyxia/hyperledger/hello_world/chaincode_example01.go:31: cannot use new(SimpleChaincode) (type *SimpleChaincode) as type shim.Chaincode in argument to shim.Start:
    *SimpleChaincode does not implement shim.Chaincode (wrong type for Init method)
        have Init(*shim.ChaincodeStub, string, []string) ([]byte, error)
        want Init(shim.ChaincodeStubInterface, string, []string) ([]byte, error)
```

supplement info:
Ubuntu 16.04 without go language environment, use PBFT algrithm.

how to fix this problem, thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you may want to use the latest version of fabric from its official repository. 
Secondly, the error is self-explanatory,

```
  *SimpleChaincode does not implement shim.Chaincode (wrong type for Init method)
        have Init(*shim.ChaincodeStub, string, []string) ([]byte, error)
        want Init(shim.ChaincodeStubInterface, string, []string) ([]byte, error)
```

You need to replace  `stub *shim.ChaincodeStub` with `stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface` everywhere in your go file. Please read this as well, https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/ibm-blockchain-issues/issues/29